# Building QT libraries on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: qt, ubuntu, build

I am trying to build QT libraries 4.8.2 on Ubuntu Linux by following the instruction mentioned in the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/install-x11.html) .

This is the second time I am trying building... I tried earlier also and when build process did not complete even after 12-13 hrs I thought something is wrong so I started from beginning.

It's been almost 24 hrs I issued make command (In the second attempt) the build process is still going on. Terminal is not showing any error either.

Does building QT libraries on Ubuntu Linux really takes this much time or I have missed something.

Comment: Unless your computer is extremely old and slow, it should not be taking 12+ hours. On a decent modern computer, I might worry after even an hour.

Comment: I am using amazon ec2 micro instance.

Comment: I don't know the expected compile performance of Qt on ec2 micro, but I would still imagine 12 hours is a long time.

Comment: Please check the build log to find does it build the same file repeatedly. If you find it, there maybe something wrong in system time of computer. also there maybe something wrong in the time stamp of source file. Touch the all files in the source tree, then retry build.

Comment: Finally, build process successfully completed in around 30 hrs.

Comment: the ec2 micro is *slow*

Comment: I found that ccache helps a lot on the next build.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Building Qt takes a couple of hours even on a fast system if you only do the default non-parallel build.  By default it also pulls in lots of libraries that you may not need.

So the first thing to try is `make -j` to do parallel builds.  If that is still taking too long then try to slim down the libraries Qt generates.  Do you need QtWebKit for instance?  If you plan on using an embedded web browser in your application then you'll want it. If not then you can halve the time of your build.  Type `configure --help` to see the [options](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/configure-options.html).  Some useful ones that can reduce the build time are:

NOTE: some of the following options are no longer applicable in Qt5

- -fast - Use this if you are just using Qt rather than developing Qt itself
- -no-webkit - If you don't need the embedded web browser this makes a huge difference
- -release - If you don't need the debug libraries then this can be quicker
- -no-qt3-support - you won't need this for a new project
- -nomake examples - don't build the examples
- -nomake demos - don't build the demos
- -no-declarative - If you're not using the QtQuick APIs then omit this
- -nomake docs - don't build the documentation (this can save a lot of time)

If you're having to pay for the time in this Amazon instance then another option is to create a local Ubuntu machine (on a spare machine or in a virtual machine) and tweak the options there until you get something that works, then use that build configuration on your Amazon instance.

EDIT:

In Qt5, the project changed to use git submodules, so if you are building from a git checkout then the default behaviour is to clone all the submodules, which will add substantially to your build times if there are modules you don't need.  There is a script `init-repository` that is part of the qt5 repository. You can use that to trim your local repository to only contain the submodules you need.  So for instance:

```
git clone https://git.gitorious.org/qt/qt5.git
cd qt5
./init-repository --module-subset="qtbase qtdeclarative qtquick1"
configure --your-options-here
make -j
```

On my machine I can do a basic build of qtbase in about 10 minutes

Comment: Building qt5.7 only qtbase here on core2duo machine running for almost 1.5 hours! I must be doing something wrong!

Comment: A core2duo is very underpowered for doing C++ development work, so this isn't very surprising.

Answer (score 0):

memory requirements to compile Qt 4.7 are **1.2 Gb** (mostly demanded by QWebKit link stage), if you don't have enough create an extra swap file (see https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s2-swap-creating-file.html)